# Python3 How to multiply all sequential items in a list by the previous item in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble trying to finish my code for an assignment...

"Teachers in most school districts are paid on a schedule that provides a salary based on their number of years of teaching experience. For example, a beginning teacher in the mySchool School District might be paid $30,000 the first year. For each year of experience after this first year, up to 10 years, the teacher receives a 2% increase over the preceding value.

Write a program that displays a salary schedule, in tabular format, for teachers in a school district. The inputs are the starting salary, the percentage increase, and the number of years in the schedule. Each row in the schedule should contain the year number and the salary for that year."

I started this assignment and felt like I was making pretty decent and (at least for me) intelligent coding. But with the amount of time it's been taking me to figure out where I'm stuck at, I've began to question if it's because I'm 'barkin up the wrong tree' so to speak.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    startSalary = int(input("Please enter beginning salary: "))
    percentIncrease = (float(input("Please enter percentage increase: ")) / 100)
    numberYears = list(range(1,(int(input("Please enter number of years in schedule: ")) + 1))

    '''
    x = percentIncrease
    y = numberYears #LIST#
    z = startSalary
    '''
    def percentFunc(x,y,z):
        for years in y:
            y[0] = z #startSalary
            y[1:] = z * x #percentIncrease
```

I'm trying to assign numberYears[0] to startSalary, and then sequentially assign the remaining 9 items (is this properly achieved with numberYears[1:]?) to the value of the previous list item multiplied by percentIncrease.

Am I just going about this all wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Consider adding a homework tag

Comment: `itertools.accumulate()` can implement these first order relationships.

Comment: Why is `numberYears` a list?

Comment: Roy I couldn't find a tag for homework.. AChampion I was unaware of itertools thank you! juanpa.arrivillaga idk that's how I saw it in my mind first but also that's exactly where I think my main issue was. Others have mentioned it should be an integer as well so definitely will be changing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to keep as how you started. And try use basic python so it would make sense.

```
startSalary = int(input("Please enter beginning salary: "))
percentIncrease = (float(input("Please enter percentage increase: ")) / 100)
numberYears = list(range(1,(int(input("Please enter number of years in schedule: ")) + 1)))


def calculateSalary(startSalary, percentIncrease, numberYears):
  for year in numberYears:

    salaryInc = startSalary*percentIncrease
    newSalary = startSalary+salaryInc
    startSalary = newSalary
    print("{} year salary is  {:0.2f}".format(year, newSalary))

calculateSalary(startSalary, percentIncrease, numberYears)
```

Comment: Thank you for doing it this way!

Answer (score 1):

Use `numberYears` as an integer, then you can use the same math used to calculate compound taxes:

```
numberYears = int(input("Please enter number of years in schedule: "))
for i in range(1,numberYears):
    print("year ", i, ", salary: ", startSalary*((1+percentIncrease)**(i-1)))

>>> 
Please enter beginning salary: 3000
Please enter percentage increase: 2
Please enter number of years in schedule: 5
year  1 , salary:  3000.0
year  2 , salary:  3060.0
year  3 , salary:  3121.2
year  4 , salary:  3183.6240000000003
```

Answer (score 0):

Build each year at once with something like:

```
def percent_func(percent_per_year, years, start_salary):
    table = []
    for i in range(years):
        table.append((i+1, start_salary))
        start_salary += round(start_salary * percent_per_year / 100.0)
    return table
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the solution helps.
`numberOfYears` should be an integer.

```
def percentFunc(x, y, z):
    """
    x = percentIncrease
    y = numberYears #SHOULD BE INTEGER#
    z = startSalary
    """

    result = [z]

    for year in range(1, y):
        last_salary = result[len(result) - 1]
        result.append(last_salary + last_salary* x/100)

    return result

x, y, z = 2, 10, 30000
print (percentFunc(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

The user inputs their Salary, Increase Percentage, and Years to be calculated. The code multiplies sequential items in a list by the previous item in the list.

Started range with 0 years as 1 and finished endyear+1

```
startSalary = int(input("Please enter beginning salary: "))
percentIncrease = (float(input("Please enter percentage increase: ")) / 100)
numberYears = int(input("Please enter number of years in schedule: "))
for i in range(1,numberYears+1):
    print("{} year salary is  {:0.2f}".format(
        i, 
        startSalary * ((1 + percentIncrease) ** (i - 1))))
```